# How to compare values of two columns in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I need to compare two columns which has below values and get a consolidated value in PostgreSQL. For an Id value, if all is green OR red, I want GREEN or RED to be returned respectively and even if one is RED, I want RED to be returned. Can someone please help? Thanks

```
ID     STATUS
1      GREEN
1      GREEN
1      RED
2      GREEN
2      GREEN
2      GREEN
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want string aggregation:

```
select id, string_agg(distinct status, ' or ' order by status) statuses
from mytable
group by id
```

If you want a single value returned, with priority given to "RED", then:

```
select id, max(status)
from mytable
group by id
```

This works because, string-wise, "RED" is greater than "GREEN". You don't specify what to do if there are more than two columns, so the answer does not address that.

Comment: It is returning the result as below. How do I get 'RED' only under statuses ?                                          appid statuses
1 GREEN or RED
2 GREEN

Comment: It should return either RED or GREEN is what I meant